# Proper way to communicate with a running python from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, windows, flask

My goal:

1. A running **python** keeps changing the value of a variable.
2. Real-time showing the changing value on browser using **html and javascript** as long as the python is changing the value.

The following is my googled solution:

1. Write the python code using **Flask**
2. Request to run the python via **Ajax** from javascript
3. The python responds the variable as JSON back to javascript

Base on this solution, I have the following questions and feel free to correct me if there were any misunderstandings.

1. The python has to be executed manually first, then the javascript can send a ajax request to `http://localhost:5000/[...some @app.route()]`. I need the python **starts running infinitely**(while loop) after the first ajax request.
2. The Flask python **can not have a while loop**. Not sure the mechanism of `app.run()` in Flask.
3. Once the first point is achieved, the javascript also has to **keep updating** the html once the python is changing the variable. Now it seems that I have to keep sending ajax request to get the variable from the python.

Really appreciate any information to address my questions!

Comment: @georg has given you a nice outline. Note that _running pythons_ can wear all sorts of shoes like Flask, Pyramid, Django (or just go barefoot). Also, be aware that JavaScript is a pretty good runner itself in some cases (also lots of shoes to choose from). In other words, depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish you may not need Python and/or any of the related frameworks.

Comment: thanks, reason I choose this combination(python and javascript) is because javascript can not access variable using memory address. Hence, I choose to let python to handle this part for javascript. Any good work-around?

Comment: No way that I know of to get the memory address of a JavaScript variable. That said, I'm not sure what you are doing to initialize and change the value of the variable in your question, so can't comment on whether or not you could actually dispense with the server-side aspect of your plan but if what you are doing doesn't require some sort of persistent storage then JavaScript and the like are certainly worth considering to simplify your process.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need three parts

- your python loop A
- a web application B
- and a javascript application C

You can combine A+B into one process, in which case you'll have to run the loop in a separate thread, or you can use any IPC means available, like shared memory/pipes/sockets, to communicate between A and B. A simple solution would be to use a database server, to which A writes and from which B reads.

If A and B are separate, then B doesn't have to be python, you can write it in js or php or everything else.

To avoid polling on the client side, you can use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) to communicate between B and C.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure my understanding: for A and B, I can use flask and multi-threading in python. For B and C communication, I should use websocket in javascript instead of ajax.

Comment: @ctheadn8954: yep, that's correct.

Comment: Oh! after searching a bit. It seems that I still have to run the python manually first. Is it possible to launch python from javascript??

Comment: @ctheadn8954: server python from client javascript? nope

Comment: yes. Sad to know that but got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run the while loop in another thread or process, for example using [flask-celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/)

the javascript updating can be achieved with [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: georg is right, websockets io is probably a better solution